# i got an error while for doing a backend the error is its shows no such column : year(sqlite3)

Tags: sqlite

I have a problem here i am unable to find my error,my error shows `no such column :year)`

```
       import sqlite3
        def connect():
            conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
            cur=conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,title text,author text,year integer,isbn integer)")
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
        def insert(title,author,year,isbn):
            conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
            cur=conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO book VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)",(title,author,year,isbn))
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
        def view():
            conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
            cur=conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM book")
            rows=cur.fetchall()
            conn.close()
            return rows 
        def search(title="",author="",year="",isbn=""):
            conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
            cur=conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE title=? OR author=? OR year=? OR isbn=?",(title,author,year,isbn))
            rows=cur.fetchall()
            conn.close()
            return rows 
        connect()
        #insert("The Earth","John Smith",1918,913123133)
        print(view())
        print(search(author="John Smith"))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Please check for typos.

Comment: Is that supposed to be python?

Comment: This seems to be sqlite related. I do not see anything mysql.

Comment: its python, its sqlite3 ,i am creating a app so i am getting error.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].